# Storing Spring State machine for an object

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am new to Spring State machine,however i have gone through the examples.How should one attach Spring state to an instance of an Class.Should it be stored as an attribute of type  String in the class.Also how to make the object store the state

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54995728/1007273 and see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707075/1007273