# How to add dynamic parameters to spring state machine action?

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I have this simple state machine configuration :

```
@Configuration 
@EnableStateMachine 
public class SimpleStateMachineConfiguration extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<State, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<State, Boolean> states) throws Exception {
        states.withStates()
                .initial(State.INITIAL)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(State.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<State, Boolean> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
            .withExternal() 
                .source(State.INITIAL)
                .target(State.HAS_CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
                .event(true)
                .action(retrieveCustomerAction()) 
                // here I'd like to retrieve the customer from this action, like:
                // stateMachine.start();
                // stateMachine.sendEvent(true);
                // stateMachine.retrieveCustomerFromAction();
            .and()
            .withExternal()
                .source(State.INITIAL)
                .target(State.NO_CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
                .event(false)
                .action(createCustomerAction()); 
                // here I'd like to send the customer instance to create, like:
                // stateMachine.start();
                // stateMachine.sendEvent(false);
                // stateMachine.sendCustomerToAction(Customer customer);
    }

    @Bean
    public Action<State, Boolean> retrieveCustomerAction() {
        return ctx -> System.out.println(ctx.getTarget().getId());
    }

    @Bean
    public Action<State, Boolean> createCustomerAction() {
        return ctx -> System.out.println(ctx.getTarget().getId());
    }

}
```

Is it possible to improve actions definition to be able to interact with them with dynamics parameters ?
How could I add consumer or provider behaviors to those actions ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to improve actions definition to be able to interact
>   with them with dynamics parameters?

Yes, it's possible. You can store the variables in the context store and retrieve then wherever you want.

```
public class Test {

  @Autowired
  StateMachine<State, Boolean> stateMachine;

  public void testMethod() {

    stateMachine.getExtendedState().getVariables().put(key, value);
    stateMachine.start();
    stateMachine.sendEvent(true);
  }
}
```

And You can retrieve this value from the context using the key. Suppose the value was of the type String then it can be retrieved like this:-

```
    @Bean
    public Action<State, Boolean> retrieveCustomerAction() {
        return ctx -> {
        String value = ctx.getExtendedState().get(key, String.class);
        // Do Something
        };
    }
```

For more you can refer the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-extendedstate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992727/spring-state-machine-attaching-static-data-to-states)

> How could I add consumer or provider behaviors to those actions?

Can you elaborate more on this question